# DocuSignAPI call Connection Refused

Tags: docusignapi

I am recieving a  "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://demo.docusign.net refused" exception when trying to connect to start the embedded signing envelope request using serverside java HTTP call with a proxy server in between.

Is there a limitation of the number of requests per hour?

Answer (score 2):

DocuSign imposes a limitation of 1,000 API calls per hour for an account.  See the ***DocuSign API Best Practices Guide*** for information about this limitation:  http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/SOAP_REST_API_Best_Practices_with_Connect_Guide.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

I was using a HTTP proxy instead of a HTTPS proxy, the proxy in between me and docusign was causing the issue.